# How to transfer on truffle develop

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I made this contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract MyTransfer {
    address owner;
    uint data;
    uint private amount;
    string greeting = "Hello World";
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function greet () constant public returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }
    function deposit() public payable {
        amount += msg.value;
    }
    function withdraw() public {
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    }
    function kill () public {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

Compile and deploy successfully finished.

Then on truffle develop console.

```
mt = MyTransfer.at(MyTransfer.address);

>mt.greet();
```

works

```
>mt.deposit(1);
```

> Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

How can I make transfer on truffle console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because your deposit() function is not waiting for any params. You need to send some value with your transaction in order for it to work. Try this:

```
mt.deposit({value: 'the amount of ether you want to send'});
```